# AcquireTokenAsync gets Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: azure-active-directory, certificate, access-token

As part of ECR, I'm changing our code to get token by using subject name instead of the thumbprint of our aad 1st party application.
I made a few changes:
1. I added the subject name to the "subject name + issuer" in the aad portal.
2. added the "sendX5c: true" parameter to the AcquireTokenAsync function call.

I'm getting the certificate from my machine but when trying to acquire the token I'm getting this exception: AADSTS7000213: Invalid certificate chain. with the inner exception of "Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)".

Any idea what am I doing wrong or what is missing?

I followed this link: https://aadwiki.windows-int.net/index.php?title=Subject_Name_and_Issuer_Authentication

Answer (score 0):

If you want to request Azure AD access token with client certificate, please refer to the following steps

1. Upload the information of the cert to Azure

   a. get the information

   ```
    $Thumbprint="930CFA423637129DB45921320B0BB451BD58A813"
   $cert=Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My\$Thumbprint
   $rawCert = $cert.GetRawCertData()
   $base64Cert = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($rawCert)
   $rawCertHash = $cert.GetCertHash()
   $base64CertHash = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($rawCertHash)
   $KeyId = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
   ```

   b. upload the above information to Azure

```
      Connect-AzureAD

    $clientAadApplication=Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "AppId eq '<you client id>'"

    New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId $clientAadApplication.ObjectId  -CustomKeyIdentifier "$base64CertHash"  -Type AsymmetricX509Cert -Usage Verify -Value $base64Cert
```

2. Get access token(I use the sdk `Microsoft.Identity.Client`)

```
              String subjectname="";




                X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My,StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates;

                X509Certificate2Collection currentCerts = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
                X509Certificate2Collection signingCert = currentCerts.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subjectname, false);
                X509Certificate2 cer = signingCert.OfType<X509Certificate2>().OrderByDescending(c => c.NotBefore).FirstOrDefault();

                var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("<client id>")
                   .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "<tenant id>")
                   .WithCertificate(cer)
                   .Build();
                var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
                Console.Read();
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials) and the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph)